# Does "simplicial" commute with "Bousfield localization"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $M$ be a model category and $S \subseteq \operatorname{Mor}(M)$ a set of arrows in (the underlying strict category of) $M$.  Recall that the [left Bousfield localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bousfield_localization) $L_SM$ of $M$ with respect to $S$ is the model category structure on the same underlying category as $M$, with the same cofibrations, more weak equivalences, and correspondingly fewer fibrations; it is the universal model category structure with these properties in which the elements of $S$ are weak equivalences.

Let $M^\Delta$ denote the category of simplicial objects in $M$.  It has two related model category structures: the *injective* one, in which cofibrations and weak equivalences are "levelwise" (and hence fibrations are [complicated](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Reedy+model+structure)), and the *projective* one, in which fibrations and weak equivalences are levelwise (and cofibrations are [more complicated](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6873)).  I am interested in both structures, so in some sense this question is really two questions.

> **Question:** Is $(L_SM)^\Delta$ a left Bousfield localization of $M^\Delta$?  What is an explicit description of the maps at which you localize?

I expect the answer is "yes", and that you can localize at the set of maps in $M^\Delta$ that are levelwise in $S$.  These seems like the type of thing that should be provable by definition unpacking.  But I got stuck somewhere, suggesting that maybe there is a subtlety.  The worry is that perhaps there just aren't a lot of levelwise-$S$-maps in $M^\Delta$, so that testing just against the levelwise-$S$-maps  might give false positives when you are trying to find out if an object is levelwise-$S$-local.

Comment: As Tyler Lawson points out in the answers, I misunderstood (probably a lot about) injective versus Reedy structures; the "complicated" link doesn't illustrate just how complicated things are.  Like, I think, many users of model categories, I in fact only case about Bousfield localizations of presheaf categories, and only for pretty well-behaved bases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the injective model structure or the Reedy model structure, the answer is yes: this is a left Bousfield localization.

For any $X \in M$, define $\Delta[n] \otimes X$ to be the element of $M^\Delta$ given by
$$
(\Delta[n] \otimes X)_k = \coprod_{(\Delta[n])_k} X,
$$
with maps induced by the natural maps on coproducts. This is a functor which is a left adjoint:
$$
Hom_{M^\Delta}(\Delta[n] \otimes X, Y) = Hom_M(X,Y_n).
$$
Moreover, $\Delta[n] \otimes (-)$ preserves cofibrations in both the injective and Reedy model structures, and so $[\Delta[n] \otimes X,Y] = [X,Y_n]$ for fibrant $Y$. Thus, in these cases localizing with respect to maps of the form $\Delta[n] \otimes f$ for $f \in S$ gives you $(L_S M)^\Delta$.

However, $\Delta[n] \otimes f$ is (except in the case $n=0$) unlikely to be levelwise in $S$ unless $S$ is closed under finite coproducts.

(Quick comment: the Reedy model structure you linked to does not have its cofibrations defined levelwise.)

Comment: Great.  I agree that what I linked to does not define cofibrations levelwise.  But I think that for $\Delta$, the Reedy and injective model structures agree?  I would have to think a lot about how to prove that directly, but my impression was that it was reasonably known.  The reference I know is to http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.1066, although the claim about $\Delta$ seems to be older.

Comment: Or, no, I've misunderstood.  For $M = \mathrm{sSet}$, they agree, not in general.  My apologies.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Right, that's a particular nicety of simplicial sets (essentially, cofibrations are levelwise monomorphisms) that doesn't have an analogue in general.

Comment: It should be also pointed out that $\Delta$ being an elegant Reedy category means that in the category of simplicial diagrams over $\Delta^{\mathrm{op}}$ the Reedy and injective model structures coincide. However, $\Delta^{\mathrm{op}}$ is not elegant and the same is not true for diagrams over $\Delta$.

Comment: @KarolSzumiło: Great.  Incidentally, I advocate the following notation: $X^Y$ means $X$-valued presheaves on $Y$, and not functors.  I would write $^YX$ for the category of $X$-valued copresheaves on $Y$.  The reason is that I think of right modules as contravariant functors.